# Mocking behavior of an object created using static factory method

Tags: java, mockito

I am refactoring a Hibernate mapped object `Gadget` to remove `getIntFieldValue` and `setIntFieldValue` and changing my code to retrieve that value from a DAO object, which is created using a `Factory` and to which a Gadget is passed.

```
public class GadgetPropertyAccessFactory {

    public static GadgetPropertyDAO getGadgetPropertyDAO(Session dbSessn){

        if(getSomeBooleanFromDB(dbSessn)) {

            return new TrueImplGadgetPropertyDAO();

        } else {

            return new FalseImplGadgetPropertyDAO();
        }
    }

    ...
```

The test code looks like this:

```
//this mocks a Gadget
Gadget gadget = createGadget();

//this is to be replaced
when(gadget.getIntFieldValue()).thenReturn(2);

DoerClass doerClass = new DoerClass(null, gadget);

List<Result> doerResults = doerClass.produceResults();

for (Result doerResult : doerResults) {
    //...
}
```

The `DoerClass` looks something like this

```
Session dbSessn;
Gadget gadget;

public DoerClass(Session dbSessn, Gadget gadget) {
    this.dbSessn = dbSessn;
    this.gadget = gadget;
}

public List<Result> produceResults() {

    //this is to be replaced
    int intFieldValue = this.gadget.getIntFieldValue()
    //with
    //GadgetPropertyDAO gadgPropDAO = GadgetPropertyAccessFactory.getGadgetPropertyDAO(this.dbSessn);
    //int intFieldValue = gadgPropDAO.getDeviceIntFieldValue(this.gadget);


    //generate List<Result> based on intFieldValue

}
```

My problem is that before I was able to conveniently mock what `getIntFieldValue` will return in `produceResults` but now that I am using a statically returned DAO, I do not know if it is possible to mock what `GadgetPropertyDAO.getDeviceIntFieldValue(this.gadget)` will return.

Is a mock possible without changing my method signatures (API)?

Comment: It sounds like your design is going backwards -- your `DoerClass` should not be responsible for retrieving a gadget from the DAO.

Comment: it is not retrieving a gadget.  the gadget is passed to it via the constructor.  the produceResults needs the refactored fields that are somewhere else in the DB and now accessed via the factored DAO

Comment: My mistake -- still, retrieving the DAO like that is the problem here. My suggestion is to go for a more dependency-injection style approach and provide the `GadgetPropertyDAO` as a constructor argument as well. Then you can mock the `getDeviceIntFieldValue` call.

Comment: Try using PowerMock combined with Mockito. I think you could mock `GadgetPropertyAccessFactory.getGadgetPropertyDAO(this.dbSessn)` and return a mock of `GadgetPropertyDAO`. Check this for the details: http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Tom G: Mockito and dependency injection (and arguably Java itself) are really designed for instances much more than static methods—it's the only way to take advantage of Java's polymorphic advantages. If you switch to making your factory an instance, it would look like this:

```
public class GadgetPropertyAccessFactory {
  public GadgetPropertyDAO getGadgetPropertyDAO(Session dbSessn){
    if(getSomeBooleanFromDB(dbSessn)) {
      return new TrueImplGadgetPropertyDAO();
    } else {
      return new FalseImplGadgetPropertyDAO();
    }
  } // ...
}

public class DoerClass {
  Gadget gadget;
  Session dbSessn;
  // Sets default implementation. Constructor injection would also work.
  GadgetPropertyAccessFactory gpaFactory = new GadgetPropertyAccessFactory();

  public DoerClass(Session dbSessn, Gadget gadget) {
    this.dbSessn = dbSessn;
    this.gadget = gadget;
  }

  public List<Result> produceResults() {
    GadgetPropertyDAO gadgPropDAO =
        gpaFactory.getGadgetPropertyDAO(this.dbSessn);
    int intFieldValue = gadgPropDAO.getDeviceIntFieldValue(this.gadget);
    // ...
  }
}

// in your test
DoerClass doerClass = new DoerClass(null, gadget);
GadgetPropertyAccessFactory mockFactory =
    Mockito.mock(GadgetPropertyAccessFactory.class);
doerClass.gpaFactory = mockFactory;
// ...
```

Another option is to live with and manage your testing gap:

```
public List<Result> produceResults() {
  return produceResultsInternal(gpaFactory.getGadgetPropertyDAO(this.dbSessn));
}

/** Visible only for testing. Do not call outside of tests. */
List<Result> produceResultsInternal(GadgetPropertyDAO gadgPropDAO) {
  int intFieldValue = gadgPropDAO.getDeviceIntFieldValue(this.gadget);
  // ...
}
```

...which then allows you to test against `produceResultsInternal` with a mock, which gets you 80% tested with 20% of the grief.